# How do I delete a Goerli testnet token?

Tags: tokens, goerli

I am testing an NFT on Goerli and all looks good. However my tutorial says that I need to delete the testnet token before deploying to mainnet, IF I had done any editing while on testnet. I did indeed edit, and am now stuck trying to delete the testnet token on Goerli, since the tutorial did not explain how to do that. Thx

Comment: Provide the code of your contract or link to your testnet deployment. Otherwise, the question is incomplete, and it will be impossible to answer.

Answer (score 2):

Generally speaking, you don't have to do that. All you need to do is find a new address and deploy your mainnet token on the new address because:

1. You are probably deploying a standard token like ERC-20.
2. There is prob no verified code on the testnet.
3. When you delete something on the Blockchain, you don't really delete it because it is always traceable.

But in case you want to overwrite/delete the smart contract, here are a few resources that may come in handy:

- [Upgradable smart contract](https://docs.openzeppelin.com/learn/upgrading-smart-contracts)
- With [selfdestruct](https://solidity-by-example.org/hacks/self-destruct/) method

Otherwise, it is impossible to modify/delete a smart contract.

Hope this helps, happy coding.

Comment: My personal practice is to add extension to the contract name like V1, V2, etc to distinguish deployed contract besides address on chain.